# preg_match works in 'Hifi Reg Tester' but returns 'false' in code

Tags: php, regex, email, preg-match

Sorry to ask a so simple question but here is my problem. I'm actually modifying the PlancakeEmailParser to fit my needs.

I made a simple regex :

```
/([^:]+) (<+.*>)$/
```

that should match with :

```
John DOE <johndoe@fakemail.com>
```

I tested it in http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex it works perfectly

But in my code it returns false !

Here is the offending code :

```
preg_match('/([^:]+): ?(.*)$/', $line, $matches);
$newHeader = strtolower($matches[1]);

$string = $matches[2];
$reg = "/([^:]+) (<+.*>)$/";

echo 'VALUE: '.$string."\n";
echo 'PREG_MATCH: '.preg_match($reg, $string)."\n\n";

if (preg_match('/([^:]+) (<+.*>)$/', $matches[2])) {
    echo('match'."\n\n\n\n");
} else {
    $value = $matches[2];
}
```

Here is the echo feedback :

```
VALUE: John DOE <johndoe@fakemail.com>
PREG_MATCH: 0
```

Does anyone of you understand what is the problem ?

Thank you very much !

EDIT

The problem was that I made an htmlentities on the all content, so the <> where converted.

The solution is to rewrite the regex from this :

```
/([^:]+) (<+.*>)$/
```

to this

```
/([^:]+) (&lt;+.*&gt;)$/
```

Thank you very much Peter Alfvin for tryin to help :)

Maybe it could help someone someday

Comment: Could you set this up someplace where we could look at it? Your literal string and regex work at http://ideone.com/a03zr4

Comment: SOLVED

The problem was that I made an htmlentities on the all content, so the <> where converted.

The solution is to rewrite the regex from this :

    /([^:]+) (<+.*>)$/

to this

    /([^:]+) (&lt;+.*&gt;)$/

Maybe it could help someone someday

Comment: @FloFlow Please remove that `+` here `&lt;+.*&gt;`. It's a quantifier and useless in this case. So it should look like `/([^:]+) (&lt;.*&gt;)$/`. Also it is totally fine to put that as an answer, well it's recommended. That way, we have a complete Q&A :)

Comment: @HamZa AS I have 1 as reputation I can't answer my own question before 7 hours ^^' but I will as soon as it will be available. Plus I finally changed my mind, I deleted the htmlentities on the global content and will put it when it will be necessay. And finally I'm using this regex how is more simple and fit my needs `'/(.*) <(.*)>$/'`. Sorry, I'm still really beginner in regex usage, and thank you for your feedback !

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED The problem was that I made an **htmlentities** on the all content, so the <> where converted. The solution is to rewrite the regex from this :

```
/([^:]+) (<+.*>)$/ to this /([^:]+) (&lt;+.*&gt;)$/
```

or remove the htmlentities from all content and use it only when needed, which I finally did !

Maybe it could help someone someday...